# stack corruption in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SRC_BUFF_SIZE 32
#define DST_BUFF_SIZE 8

int tempfn1(char *p)
{
    printf("p %p\n", p);
    return 0;
}

int tempfn(char *ip, int size)
{
    char pttt[DST_BUFF_SIZE];
    printf("ip %p\n", ip);
    tempfn1(ip);
    // ERROR - copying more data to a local buffer of 4 bytes

    //memcpy(pttt, ip, size); // This will lead to stack corruption as     
                              // the size exceeds the size of destination

    // IDEALLY the copy should be done with min of size of destination buffer 
    // or source size rather than source size... 
    // anyways dest can hold only the size so it is better to crop the buffer 
    // than to crash due to overflow. 
    // proper call is as follows
    #define MIN(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
    memcpy(pttt, ip, MIN(size, DST_BUFF_SIZE));

    printf("ip %p\n", ip);
    tempfn1(ip);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char ip[SRC_BUFF_SIZE] = {0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 
    0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 
    0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 
    0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2, 0xe2 };
    tempfn(ip, SRC_BUFF_SIZE);
    return 0;
}
```

This a sample program to avoid stack corruption. Is there any other function to check length of destination as well as the source inorder to avoid stack corruption?

Comment: Normally, you should never put explicit work in to "avoiding stack corruption". You should just program correctly.

Comment: Note that you **must** cast the argument for `%p` to `void *` to avoid undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept which you are pointing to doesn't apply only to stack corruption. It is applied in general to avoid memory overflow. A memory overflow can lead to corruption of stack when used with stack variable, or heap when used with heap variable. Basically it leads to undefined behavior.

The best way to avoid this is to:

1. To program correctly (i.e. with proper logic) as Kerrek SB correctly points out in his comment.
2. To use functions like strncpy instead of strcpy, strncat instead of strcat etc which will help in applying the same concept of safety which you have tried to apply here.

The following two links about Secure Coding Guidelines and Practices might be of some help:

http://www.atsec.com/downloads/pdf/secure-coding-guidelines.pdf 
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/Top+10+Secure+Coding+Practices

Comment: Thats a very good site you mentioned. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your question literally boils down to-

> Given a pointer, find the size of the memory block it is pointing to

which is *impossible* and doesn't make sense as well. So to make this *hard* question simpler, you need to make some assumptions such as the pointer is a `char` pointer and `\0` would be treated as the `End-Of-Block` indicator. Then you can use functions like `strlen` etc

But in your given case none of this holds good and what you are doing ( using `MIN` ) seems OK and is as close you can get to what you want.